# How to implement a Linked List in secondary memory and not in RAM?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I'm curious to know whether there is a way to implement any data structure in secondary storage or not?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Traditionally, many data structures we use today have been used as on-disk structures.  However, it's much harder to dynamically add and delete elements, especially if they're different sizes.  The hard disk will also seek a lot if the elements are scattered throughout the file, and that will really slow down your program.

To save a linked list in a file, your "next" pointer is typically the offset of the next element within the file.  To read the next element, you seek to that offset, and read the structure into RAM.

That's if you want one big file with your entire linked list.  Another way you can put a linked list onto secondary storage is to have each entry be a separate file, and your "next" pointer is the filename of the next element.  That makes it easier to add and remove elements (that's just file creation and deletion, and updating the pointers if needed), but does even more seeking.